# Apply a TableCellRenderer on a single cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecellrenderer

I am trying to be able to color separate cells in a JTable, but I got only so far to apply a TableCellRenderer on a whole column, which then obviously malfunctions. I have a custom JTable:

```
public class JColorTable extends JTable{
  (...)
  public void setCellColor(int col, int row, Color newColor) {
    getColumnModel().getColumn(col).setCellRenderer(new ColorField(col, row, newColor, background));
    repaint();
  }
}
```

ColorField looks like this:

```
class ColorField extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    (...))

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
            boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        if (row == newRow && column == newCol) {
            l.setBackground(Color.red);
        } else {
            l.setBackground(defaultColor);
        }

        return l;
    }
}
```

This works like a charm when I have a single colored cell in a column, but when I try to color another cell in that column, the previous gets deleted (due to the condition in ColorField not applying for the previous column).

Is there a way to only apply ColorField to a single cell, rather than the whole column? If so, how? I did not find anything suitable, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`JTable` has a method `getCellRenderer()` that you can override. It is called when a cell needs rendering and returns one based on the row and column.

Your `JTable` would need to keep some record of which renderer to use for each cell (by row and column). A 2D array would do it or a `Map` with the key being an X,Y value.

Add a method to set the renderer on a particular cell (by row and column) and there you go.

```
class MyTable extends JTable {

    // all the other JTable stuff goes here too ...

    public TableCellRenderer getCellRenderer(int row, int column) {
        TableCellRenderer myRenderer = getCustomRenderer(row, column);
        if (myRenderer != null) {
            return myRenderer;
        }
        // else...
        return super.getCellRenderer(row, column);
    }

    private Map<Integer, Map<Integer, TableCellRenderer>> rendererMap = new ...;

    public void setCustomRenderer(int row, int column, TableCellRenderer renderer) {
        Map<Integer, TableCellRenderer> m1 = rendererMap.get(row);
        if (m1 == null) {
            m1 = new ...;
            rendererMap.put(row, m1);
        }
        m1.put(column, renderer);
    }

    public TableCellRenderer getCustomRenderer(int row, int column) {
        Map<Integer, TableCellRenderer> m1 = rendererMap.get(row);
        if (m1 == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return m1.get(column);
    }
}
```

The default version of `getTableCellRenderer` uses the renderer set on the column if there is one, if not it uses the renderer based on the class of the cell contents. Default cell contents is `Object` in many cases. It depends on the `TableModel` used.

Comment: The getCustomRenderer method should be of type TableCellRenderer and not void.

Comment: @JorgeBlancoSegura Thank you. Fixed it. Maybe StackOverflow needs a built in Java IDE to make sure the code I type is good. :)

Comment: Please see this [cleaner implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16408257/418556).

Comment: You can specify which TableCellRender should be used to render a given class type or even assign a TableCellRender directly to a TableColumn via the ColumnModel. There's no need to extend JTable, this is very limiting, especially if you're dealing with existing source and cant change the table implementation

Answer (score 3):

Personally, I would avoid any solution that required you to extend a `JTable`. The main reason is it makes your code less portable and tightly couples your renderer to a particular implementation of `JTable`.  It might suit your needs, but, personally, I'm always trying to see a bigger picture/potential/reuse.

Remember that a cell renderer is bound to a table column. It's not meant to be able to provide custom rendering on a cell by cell basis, *per se*.  What you can do though, is provided rendering logic for each cell based a on series of conditions within the renderer.

I would probably put together some kind condition/format engine, which you could use to pass the cell value and coordinates to, which would then make decisions based on the needs of the particular implementation of the engine.

```
class ColorField extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    (...))

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value,
        boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

        super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

        // CellFormat is an object you create to hold the various aspects
        // of the cell format
        // You could also pass in the selected and focused flags if you
        // needed them...
        // getFormatEngine is a method you would write to provide
        // to gain access to the format engine
        CellFormat format = getFormatEngine().getFormatFor(value, row, column);
        setBackground(format.getBackground());
        setForeground(format.getForeground());
        setFont(format.getFont());
        // Any other properties you may wish to effect...

        return this;
    }
}
```

The `FormatEngine` would be the bases for making decisions about how best to format the given cell. It should be capable of providing a "default" format as well

This means you could devise a "default" renderer for particular cell types, but have the ability to supply custom rendering based on your needs without the need for multiple `if` statements or extending the base render

This is also the bases for a conditional formatting engine, where you could apply a series of conditions against a given value and return an appropriate format based on the results

Comment: This seems a cleaner approach than the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You need some color information for each cell in a column. This information could reside in the values:

```
class CellValue {
    Color getBackgroundColor() { ... }
    String getCellContent() { ... }
}
```

Your `getTableCellRendererComponent()` method could then look like this:

```
CellValue cellValue = (CellValue) value;
Color bgColor = cellValue.getBackgroundColor();
String text = cellValue.getCellContent();

JLabel l = (JLabel) super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, text, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);

l.setBackground(bgColor);

...
```

Of course you have to adapt your TableModel to store CellValue instances.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the correct way to implement this is via [ColorHighlighter](http://pirlwww.lpl.arizona.edu/resources/guide/software/SwingX/org/jdesktop/swingx/decorator/ColorHighlighter.html).
This is said in [the documentation](http://pirlwww.lpl.arizona.edu/resources/guide/software/SwingX/org/jdesktop/swingx/JXTable.html).  This is a [related issue in SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791719/swingx-jxtable-use-colorhighlighter-to-color-rows-based-on-a-row-object).

Note: if the table allows sorting it is **essential** to implement a corresponding ComponentAdapter, with its dapter.convertRowIndexToModel