# Highlighting certain rows in a jtable in java

Tags: java, swing

In my java swing application , i want to highlight certain rows in a jtable. How is it possible to do that using java. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) and [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer) for details

Comment: You could also look at SwingLabs `JXTable` which provides a nice row highlighting API, for [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791719/swingx-jxtable-use-colorhighlighter-to-color-rows-based-on-a-row-object)

Comment: if it worked have a courtesy to accept the answer?@visakh_vijay

Comment: See [example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24849600/2587435)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posting my code. you can understand the concepts and apply in your project.

this will work for a single column and not highlight the entire row

```
 import javax.swing.*;
    import javax.swing.table.*;
    import java.awt.*;

    class MyTableCellRender extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {

    public MyTableCellRender() {
    setOpaque(true);
    }

    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {

    String number = (String)value;
    int val = Integer.parseInt(number);

        if(val > 5){
            if(val >= 5000) {
            setForeground(Color.black);
            setBackground(Color.red);
            }
            else {
            setForeground(Color.black);
            setBackground(Color.yellow);
            }
        }
        else{
        setBackground(Color.white);
        setForeground(Color.black);
        }
     setText(value !=null ? value.toString() : "");
    return this;
    }
    }
```

Comment: You should point out that this will work for a single column and not highlight the entire row, unless you're willing to replace each cell renderer for each column...

Comment: i just wanted him to see the concept.i am not going to solve this question for him. @MadProgrammer still edited it.

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi: Very thanks for the code. Can you help how ti highlight a single cell in the table.

Comment: @visakh_vijay[refer to this it will help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24848314/change-background-color-of-jtable-row-based-on-column-value/24849600#24849600)

Comment: @DeepanshuBedi : Can you help me to highlight/unhighlight the cell based on a button click.